# Javascript - window.history(-1) into a constant

Tags: javascript, while-loop, html5-history

I'm trying to check with a while, if browser history (back two pages) is a certain url, then decrease variable `num` by -1. And then do `window.history.go(num);`

The error I get, from my understanding is related to history not being put correctly into a variable/constant.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var num = -2;
        var page = history(-2);
        if (page == 'http://www.dghsdfagasdfa.com/page4') {
            while (page == 'http://www.dghsdfagasdfa.com/page4') {
               var num = num -1;
               page = history(num);
            }
        }
        window.history.go(num);
    }, 2500);
</script>
```

I'm new to javascript, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? and what is `history` referring to?  You can't get the url of pages in `window.history`.

Comment: TypeError: history is not a function. i'm using history as part of window.history basic functions of javascript. thank you

Comment: probably need to use `window.history`, but what you are trying won't work anyway :)